# PICamera - Custom output (start_recording())

Tags: python, camera

I need access to full camera video resolution (1080p) and after searching found that recording (`start_recording()`) methods of PICamera is much better than capturing methods(`capture_continues()`) regarding speed (I've done some benchmark).

In the section [5.9. Custom outputs](http://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.10/recipes2.html#custom-outputs) of Advanced Recipes of PICamera documentation the `start_recording()` seems  redirecting camera frames (or what ever) to a custom class.

But the problem is that I don't know how to access/modify frames inside the class. I've used some other methods that people using it when accessing frames through `capture_continues()` but these codes didn't work. Seems the format of data here (inside class) is differ.

This is the sample code you can use as a custom output solution (that can be found in the PICamera documentation) :

```
from __future__ import print_function

import picamera

class MyOutput(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.size = 0

    def write(self, s):
        self.size += len(s)

    def flush(self):
        print('%d bytes would have been written' % self.size)

with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
    camera.resolution = (640, 480)
    camera.framerate = 60
    camera.start_recording(MyOutput(), format='h264')
    camera.wait_recording(10)
    camera.stop_recording()
```

This is sample code that I've used inside write method of MyOutput:

```
data = np.fromstring(s, dtype=np.uint8)
image = cv2.imdecode(data, 1)
cv2.imshow('frame2', image)
```

And this is returned error:

```
Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":1.0".
OpenCV Error: Bad flag (parameter or structure field) (Unrecognized or unsupported array type) in cvGetMat, file /usr/src/packages/BUILD/opencv-2.4.1+dfsg/modules/core/src/array.cpp, line 2482
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "home/pi/share/python/cus_out.py", line 32, in <module>
    camera.stop_recording()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/picamera/camera.py", line 976, in __exit__
    self.close()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/picamera/camera.py", line 955, in close
    self.stop_recording(splitter_port=port)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/picamera/camera.py", line 1362, in stop_recording
    self.wait_recording(0, splitter_port)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/picamera/camera.py", line 1333, in wait_recording
    encoder.wait(timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/picamera/encoders.py", line 853, in wait
    raise self.exception
cv2.error: /usr/src/packages/BUILD/opencv-2.4.1+dfsg/modules/core/src/array.cpp:2482: error: (-206) Unrecognized or unsupported array type in function cvGetMat
```

Comment: *"I need fast access to full camera video resolution"* -> Just in case this is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378), writing your own python program is unlikely to be the most direct route to that goal.  If you mean, "...in a python program" then ignore this ;)

Comment: Neat tip about XY problem :D.